# Leading Space at VBA Text File

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I am working on a code (sample below) that creates a text file from cell values.

```
fpath = ActiveSheet.Range("E3")
Open fpath For Output As #2
For i = 9 To 30
    t = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2))
    Print #2, t, vbCrLf,
Next i
Close #2
```

However, the output text file comes with some leading tab spaces (Sample below). As you can see, the first line looks perfect. Please can someone help me figure out what's going wrong?

```
22                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          mean          rms           pos           neg                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
           99.97                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
           99.97                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          -1435341521848.46                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          -1472817751812.39                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          -1746441031333.17                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          -2565650848341.7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
           1586098400722.69                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           1651484149414.77                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           1886743487015.51                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           2846137892251.89                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           0.739329734466885
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Print #2, t, vbCrLf,
```

use

```
Print #2, t
```